# MySQL warnings after column's datatype change

Tags: mysql, types

I've changed datatype of one column on my MyISAM MySQL table (over 3.5m records):

```
mysql> alter table `sometable` modify column `int_column` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

Before that my `int_column` was mediumint(8). After performing the query, I've got 377 warnings. Here is `show warnings;` query result:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 19360   | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 33745   | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 181436  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 587071  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 596617  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 659837  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 668363  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 801450  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 827911  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 835083  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 853689  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 867848  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 922569  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 922633  | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1002626 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1095119 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1102957 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1183077 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1282318 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1308876 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1311981 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1313329 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1375981 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1468411 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1470989 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1552848 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1556220 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1613484 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1619116 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1664449 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1670895 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1685828 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1689845 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1690212 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1697586 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1701220 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1710764 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1716681 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1717857 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1721820 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1721848 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1736543 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1738177 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1745430 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1748732 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1750112 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1753833 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1753903 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1762801 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1765664 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1766269 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1768134 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1786470 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1788247 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1790305 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1792769 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1795158 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1800610 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1806786 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1808764 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1820163 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1828066 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1842223 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'int_column' at row 1844030 | 
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+ 
64 rows in set (0.26 sec)
```

The question is obvious: how it is even possible that I allocate more bytes for integer field and all of a sudden it turns to be `out of range`?

There is no index on `int_column` (I don't know how it might be helpful, though).

The other question is: why `show warnings` has returned just 64 rows of 377? I'm all confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old datatype was signed, your new one is unsigned.

So you lost all negative numbers.

Show warnings has a limit to how many it will store. Use

```
SET max_error_count=....
```

To change it.

BTW, int(11) for unsigned is too large, it should be int(10). For signed you can have 11 characters because of the minus sign.

Comment: I'm sorry. Indeed it was `signed`.

Comment: Damn. I should've figured it out myself :-) Apparently I'm too overwhelmed now. Thanks a lot.